# Online booking confirmation

Tags: visas, bookings, egyptian-citizens, slovenia

The Slovenian embassy in Egypt are not accepting any online booking confirmation from websites such as booking.com, hotels.com etc. They need a direct confirmation of the hotel reservation from Slovenia which must include the full name of the person confirming the reservation (i.e the hotel owner, the hotel booking manager, etc) so I need to know how to book it & how much time mainly this confirmation will take

Comment: If you already have a online reservation, try contacting the hotel directly and ask for a booking confirmation from them

Comment: Did it usually takes much time as I have to go to the embassy maximum by next sunday

Comment: It depends how fast the hotel answers back

Comment: I used to be in that situation. I called the hotel up and I got the confirmation immediately via email which I printed and used that to apply for the visa without any problem. I recommend book 3-star-up hotel so you get a better service when you call them.

Comment: @toy post this as an answer please.

Answer (score 2):

I used to be in that situation. I called the hotel up and I got the confirmation immediately via email which I printed and used that to apply for the visa without any problem. I recommend you book 3-star-up hotel so you get a better service when you call them.

Answer (score 1):

I used to travel frequently for business, and often I had to apply for a visa for a trip I might not even make, or might make at a different time.

My travel agent was already used to making a "fake itinerary" for me - she would book a fully refundable flight and a fully refundable hotel stay, often at much higher rates, and send me the itinerary. I would use this itinerary for the visa and then simply cancel the entire trip and re-book it at my convenience - usually for a far lower fee. This solved many problems with getting visas - where embassies or consulates simply don't understand that it's 2015, that itineraries might change on a moment's notice or that booking on-line is common.

I think it is only cheating a little bit, considering that the itinerary is as real as it gets, the only thing you are not telling them is that you are very likely not to actually travel it.